# Is an empty string considered an empty parameter in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure

```
ALTER PROC myProcedure 
    @day VARCHAR (6) = NULL
as
```

Now if I call it like this

```
EXEC myProcedure @day= ''
```

What will be the result of `@day`? Will it be empty string or NULL?

My theory is, if the parameter was omitted completely, it would be NULL, but now it will be empty string. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an empty string, the param value is empty string. You can easily check by selecting the variable as shown below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('myProcedure') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC myProcedure 
GO
CREATE PROC myProcedure 
    @day VARCHAR (6) = NULL
as
BEGIN
    SELECT @day as param
END
GO
--Returns empty string in output
EXEC myProcedure @day= ''

--Returns NULL as output
EXEC myProcedure
```

**Note:** the reason NULL is returned is because the parameter is defaulted to NULL in the procedure parameter definition. If the default was omitted, the EXEC myProcedure will return an error.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought, but I couldn't check it myself for various reasons (permissions, etc.)